# What chemical or physical parameters altered during the usage of buffered versus unbuffered extractant for leachability of a soil or sediment?

Tags: geochemistry, sedimentology, soil-science

Toxicity characteristic leaching procedure (TCLP) is an extraction method to simulate a soil or sediment leaching. The method employed two extraction fluids - one is a buffered
solution of acetic acid and sodium hydroxide while the another one is an unbuffered acetic acid solution. [1] Although this protocol is widely used by many government instances, I still can not find any meaningful justification on whether first solution should and should not be able to thoroughly leach a sodiment or soil. I also can not find any theoretical, computational, or spectroscopic basis that can explain the mechanism behind the dissolution of such soils by unbuffered and buffered solutions, let it be a common ferrihydrite or goethite soil. Could there be any evidence that it might transform into an unstable hydroxide-hydrate-acetate ferrihydrite species?

Any insight **from research article** is appreciated and please do not put simple textbook explanations. Thank you very much.

[1] https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2015-12/documents/1311.pdf

Comment: this question might be a better fit for https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/